# Rejecting Incoming Calls Immediately Android

Tags: android

Can we block incoming phone calls in android before it reaches the phone application?
I have made an application to block incoming phone calls my problem is that even though the call is suspended immediately it pops up the calling screen for a second. Any suggestions how to avoid that inefficiency?
Also if there is a way to delete the phone call from the call history please let me know how to do it?

This is my main activity

```
    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_PHONE_STATE_GRANTED = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getPermission();

    }

    private void getPermission() {

      if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
      Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != 
      PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
          ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] 
          {Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
        PERMISSION_REQUEST_PHONE_STATE_GRANTED);
      }
    }
```

}

This is my CallReceiver class which extends BroadcastReceiver

```
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
    import com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony;
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;

    public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private ITelephony telephonyService;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            //make sure it's not an outgoing call
            if (telephony.getCallState() == 1) {
                try {
                    Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
                    Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                    m.setAccessible(true);
                    telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
                    telephonyService.endCall();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my manifest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.shulem.phonecallsblocker">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
        <uses-permission 
            android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category 
                       android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <receiver
                android:name=".CallReceiver"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action 
                        android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

And this is a picture of the popup screen (which pops up after the call is already suspended on the caller’s side)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvnFA.png)

Ps
 I tried to add android priority but it didn’t help.

Answer (score 1):

Relying on phone state to determine if there is an incoming call and then ending it via TelephonyManager is never going to be a reliable approach to implementing a call screening app of this nature.  The broadcasts for phone state are sent asynchronously while the system is busy doing all sorts of other things related to call setup.  So on some devices it might work, but on others there is a good chance it won't.